# Haskell scotty Action to IO

Tags: mongodb, haskell, scotty

I am back again trying to learn Haskell and, oh boy it is difficult!
I am a trying to do a simple mongoDB insertion inside a Scotty endpoint. Problem is the type return by the insert function is not accepted in the Scotty do statement. The program is quite simple:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Control.Monad.Trans(liftIO,lift,MonadIO)
import System.IO
import Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding (decodeUtf8)
import Data.Text.Lazy (pack,unpack)
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Time.Clock.POSIX
import Database.MongoDB    (Action, Document, Document, Value, access,
                            allCollections,insert, close, connect, delete, exclude, find,
                            host,findOne, insertMany, master, project, rest,
                            select, liftDB, sort, Val, at, (=:))

main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 $ do

    post "/logs" $ do
       id <- liftIO $ getTimeInMillis
       b <- body
       let decodedBody = unpack(decodeUtf8 b)
       i <- liftIO $ insertLog id decodedBody
       text $ "Ok"

--setup database connection
run::MonadIO m => Action m a -> m a 
run action = do
        pipe <- liftIO(connect $ host "127.0.0.1")
        access pipe master "data" action

getTimeInMillis ::Integral b => IO b
getTimeInMillis = round `fmap` getPOSIXTime

insertLog::MonadIO m => Int -> String -> Action m Value
insertLog id body = run $ insert "logs" ["id" =: id, "content" =: body]
```

the problem comes in the line

```hs
 i <- liftIO $ insertLog id decodedBody
```

And the type error is

```hs
 Expected type: Web.Scotty.Internal.Types.ActionT
                       Data.Text.Internal.Lazy.Text IO Value
 Actual type: Action m0 Value
```

Any help or tip will be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a different error message with that code.  Maybe you made some changes (like adding `liftIO`).

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
                         Database.MongoDB.Query.MongoContext m0 Value’
                 with ‘IO a0’
  Expected type: IO a0
    Actual type: Action m0 Value
```

In the line:

```
i <- liftIO $ insertLog id decodedBody
```

the `liftIO` function expects a genuine `IO` action, of type `IO a` for some `a`.  However, the expression `insertLog id decodedBody` doesn't represent an IO action.  It is Mongo action of type `Action m Value` for some `m` that has a `MonadIO` constraint.  You need to use some function run Mongo `Action` values in `IO`.  It looks like you've already written such a function, named `run`.  It's written for a general `MonadIO m` but can be specialized to:

```
run :: Action IO a -> IO a
```

so if you first run your Mongo action (to turn it into `IO`) and then lift that action (to run it in the Scotty action under `post`), the following should type check:

```
i <- liftIO $ run $ insertLog id decodedBody
```

*Update:*  Whoops!  I missed the `run` in the `insertLog` function.  You either want to write:

```
-- use "run" here
main = do
   ...
   i <- liftIO $ run $ insertLog id decodedBody

-- but no "run" here
insertLog::MonadIO m => Int -> String -> Action m Value
insertLog id body = insert "logs" ["id" =: id, "content" =: body]
```

**OR** you want to write:

```
-- no "run" here
main = do
   ...
   i <- liftIO $ insertLog id decodedBody

-- change the type signature and use "run" here
insertLog :: Int -> String -> IO Value
insertLog id body = run $ insert "logs" ["id" =: id, "content" =: body]
```

That will avoid the double-`run` problem.

The reason `run` didn't work as intended in your original code is a little complicated...

The problem is that `run` has flexibility to convert its Mongo action to many possible monads by returning `m a` for any `m` that supports `MonadIO m`.  Because you gave `insertLog` a type signature with return type `MonadIO m' => Action m' Value` (where I changed the variable to keep `m` and `m'` distinct), the type checker matched the return type of `run` to the return type of `insertLog`:

```
m a ~ Action m' Value
```

by setting `a ~ Value` and `m ~ Action m'`.  So, your `run` in `insertLog` was actually used with the following bizarre type:

```
run :: Action (Action m') Value -> Action m' Value
```

Normally, this would have caused a type error, but the type of `insert` is also flexible.  Instead of returning an action of type `Action IO Value`, which would be the "usual" type, it happily adapted itself to return an action of type `Action (Action IO) Value` to match what `run` was expecting.

Comment: Absolutely right! Code runs with your advise. But I do not really understand, insertLog already uses the run function. Why doesnt that worked already? Anyway thank you very much you Haskellers rock!

Comment: Oops.  I missed that.  I've updated my answer.  You'll want to avoid the double-`run` by using one of two alternatives.  With two `run`s, it'll type check, but you'll actually be performing some weird double-connection to your Mongo database that you don't really want.